# form select object dynamically changing class name with php and javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, dynamic

Having some trouble here with this.

The setup:

A `select` object with a choice of "Other"

User selects "Other".

Script runs when this specific value is chosen, and dynamically changes the `class` of `input` object from "hide" to "show" (hidden and visible with css `display`).

```
<p>Select a Grade:</p>
    <select name="grade" id="grade" onchange="changeCssClass('otherGrade')">
    <option value="No Specified Grade">Please Select</option>
    <option value="201">201</option>
        ...
    <option value="Secondary">Secondary</option>
    <option value="otherGrade">Other</option>
    </select>

<p>If "Other":</p>
<?php
    $otherGrade = $_POST['grade'];

    if($otherGrade = "otherGrade")
    {
    echo("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

        function changeCssClass(objInputID)
        {               

                    if(document.getElementById(objInputID).className=='hide')
            {
                        document.getElementById(objInputID).className = 'show';
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById(objInputID).className = 'hide';
            }
        }

        </script>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo ("");
    }
?>

<input type="text" name="otherGrade" id="otherGrade" class="hide" />
```

Should I remove the `onchange` event from the `select` object? If so, I am at a loss as how to have the script executed.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script should always be included in your page, since you want this to run while you make the changes in the dropdown list..

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    function changeCssClass(objInputID, currentVal, correctVal)
    {         
       if(correctVal == currentVal)
        {
                    document.getElementById(objInputID).className = 'show';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(objInputID).className = 'hide';
        }
    }
</script>

<p>Select a Grade:</p>
<select name="grade" id="grade" onchange="changeCssClass('otherGrade', this.value, 'otherGrade')">
<option value="No Specified Grade">Please Select</option>
<option value="201">201</option>
    ...
<option value="Secondary">Secondary</option>
<option value="otherGrade">Other</option>
</select>

<p>If "Other":</p>

<input type="text" name="otherGrade" id="otherGrade" class="hide" />
```

Live example at : http://www.jsfiddle.net/MVymF/

Answer (score 0):

why are you putting this in the post event? you can just render this as standard javascript as part of the page.

Comment: i used the post event because I couldnt figure out a way for javascript to find the specific value in the dropdown menu. i feel like this would have something to do with it... "document.forms[0].grade.options[n].value in an if/else statement.

Comment: it sounds like you might be better off just using jquery, it will save you a ton of learning curve for the little things. 

http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-select-list-values

Comment: bah, enter key is against me today. you can use the .val to get the selected item and simply use .hide()/show() on your input element instead of having to switch classes and worry about cross browser support.

Comment: i suppose i could use the jquery switchclass/addclass/removeclass but i still would have the problem of it activating when a specific value is selected.

Comment: when you create your event listener you can add conditional operators, i.e.. if (this.val() == "something") { doSomething(); }. or on your onchange definition of the select you can conditionally execute the function.

Answer (score 0):

On post , the page will be refreshing , ad on reloading you are not saving the selected value of the select box.

The select box is not keep selected after posting. You have to do that.

>Other

As the value of option change the display hide also gone.
Fix that

If no need  to submit the page . use this

http://api.jquery.com/val/

check demo of select